# Howto use PMD plugin in Eclpise 4.3 running on Java 8

Tags: eclipse, pmd

PDM brings xerces jar which is not compatible with java 8 - this has been reported here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=432118

This is the PMD plugin that I wouyld like to use: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/

Is there a way to install PMD in eclipse 4.3/4.4 on java 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a PMD bug - they have already fixed it in trunk, I've tested it and it works fine. The problem was, that it had transitive dependency to old xerces lib.

Answer (score 3):

https://sourceforge.net/p/pmd/bugs/1210/ shows current status of the fix (closed), and has the repository location to install the current snapshot version, and says the fix will be released in 4.0.4. I added the updatesite to my install locations and installed the snapshot (dated 7/29), now I have my PMD preferences/menus/perspective back in Luna 4.4 running JDK8. Thanks so much for the trunk tip.

Answer (score 1):

Had PMD plugin installation problem with Eclipse Luna 4.4.2 when I installed PMD directly from Eclipse marketplace.

To solve this,

I uninstalled the plugin and used the following link to choose 4.4 eclipse PMD plugin.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/

It worked!

Answer (score 0):

This is the Solution:

If you have previously installed a version of the PMD Eclipse plugin prior to November 2012, then you should remove/uninstall it first. To install the PMD for Eclipse plugin:

```
In Eclipse, click on Help -> Install New Software...
Click on Add..
Enter the following:
    Name: PMD for Eclipse Update Site
    URL: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd-eclipse/update-site/
and click OK.
You should see PMD for Eclipse 4. Select the checkbox next to it and click Next >.
You'll need to accept the license and confirm you want to install a plugin that is not digitally signed. Go ahead and install it anyway.
Restart eclipse
```